# Could not find com.google.firebase: when running react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, onesignal

When running react-native run-android the command fails and I get the following error in my console.

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:12.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:12.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:12.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:12.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:12.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.1.0
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:12.0.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/PhpstormProjects/easylog/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.pom
    - file:/Users/lexlemmens/PhpstormProjects/easylog/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/12.0.1/firebase-iid-interop-12.0.1.aar
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.1.0
```

My android/build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        versionCode = 15
        versionName = "1.0.15"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Required to use version 12.0.1 of com.google.android.*
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/998
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                   details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                   details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
            }
        }

        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.10.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my app/build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


/**
 *  ------------------------------------------
 *    ADD KEYSTORE PROPERTIES HERE
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */

// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystores/com.centagon.easylog.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.centagon.android.easylog"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['key.alias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['key.alias.password']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['key.store'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['key.store.password']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':amazon-cognito-identity-js')
    compile project(':@aws-amplify_pushnotification')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I'm running `react-native` 0.57.2 and `react-native-onesignal` package 3.2.12.

Already moved the google() above the jcenter() as some people suggested but without luck. Someone who can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not integrated Firebase in your project. As your dependencies in app/build.gradle should have firebase core and messaging also in MainApplication.java include new packages. And follow the complete installation guide here

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started

Or if you are not using firebase packages then remove them from package.json and other import statements.

Then clean your project by cd android && ./gradlew clean.

Comment: Thank you! Got it fixed, haven't done this though.. But it is working right now, don't remember the solution though...